# GridView can not Handle ConcurrentBag List - C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, devexpress

Here is my list:

```
private ConcurrentBag<UIResult> _Results;
```

which I have assigned it into a grid view data source:

```
gridResults.DataSource = _Results;
```

I'm sending this list into another library so it will add to this list and in UI I will update and refresh the grid view data source like this:

```
gridResults.RefreshDataSource();
```

It will work fine if I use `Ilist<UIResult>` instead of `ConcurrentBag`. But Here It won't update the data source and will not show any result inside the grid view. Where is the problem with `ConcurrentBag` and how to solve it?

I have tested this on both DevExpress and Telerik Components.

Comment: Please tag with the correct 3rd party grid component. (DevExpress XtraGrid?)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have tagged them.